# Self-contained text on characteristic classes

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, manifolds, low-dimensional-topology

I am looking for a clear, self-contained text (either a book or lecture notes) that deals with characteristic classes, starting from the very basics (fiber bundle, principal bundle etc.), and preferably dealing with the special examples of Steifel-Whitney class and Euler class.

Thanks!

Comment: If only there were a book about "Characteristic Classes" ... http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/milnstas.pdf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Milnor's book on characteristic classes is almost surely exactly what you want.

Comment: Don't forget Stasheff!

Answer (score 3):

Bott and Tu is quite self-contained.